# Using Ogg Vorbis SPI for decoding .ogg files fails for small file sizes

Tags: java, audio, ogg

I am using [Ogg Vorbis SPI](http://www.javazoom.net/vorbisspi/documents.html) as a means of decoding `.ogg` files.

The code snippet I use for loading `.ogg` files and converting to PCM is not too dissimilar from the suggested one in the documentation:

```
// The streams are valid at this point.
try (InputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(file.getInputStream(entry) );
     AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bin) ) {

    AudioFormat baseFormat = in.getFormat();
    // At this point the format is valid:
    // VORBISENC 44100.0 Hz, unknown bits per sample, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 12000.0 frames/second, 
    // I can't make a Clip directly from this or it will be all buzzy, so I convert to PCM

    // Decoding to PCM
    AudioFormat decodedFormat =
        new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                        baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                        16,
                        baseFormat.getChannels(),
                        baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
                        baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                        false);

    // This is where the issues appear...
    AudioInputStream decodedInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);

    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(decodedInputStream);

    // entry.getName is basically the filename. Any files with '0' frame length didn't get converted properly.
    System.out.println("Clip " + entry.getName() + " loaded at " + clip.getFrameLength() + " frame length");

    return clip;
} catch { ... }
```

What is happening is that I am loading several small sound files, in the range of low of 5K to high of 32K (in ogg format). A few files, however, will not convert properly to PCM. I noticed that they all have something in common; they range in size from 5K - 6K. The sound files seem to start being converted properly at around 7K. I tested this by taking an 11K sound and cutting it down until it no longer converted (~6K)

I figure that one way around it would be to add some inaudible noise to fill the size, but I would prefer just properly converting the sound file regardless of size. Being completely new to the concepts of sound representation in addition to the API itself, I don't know where to start looking to see why this may be happening.

Comment: I'm wondering if AudioInputStream.getFormat() moves the position in the stream and doesn't reset it. Maybe try closing and re-opening the stream?

Comment: Thank you for the interest; I just tried reset() and closing/opening a new stream right after I use getFormat(). The issue is, unfortunately, still occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got into the same scenario as you do, and it seems while encoding small files and files which don't fit original buffer length (it is a luck to be so) will get cut due to a bugs in Vorbis SPI implementation - it is really old and I hope they'll support it and will fix.
As a workaround you can fix DecodedVorbisAudioInputStream.java in 2 places:

```
    private int readFromStream(byte[] buffer, int index, int bufferSize_) {
    int bytes = 0;
    try {
        bytes = oggBitStream_.read(buffer, index, bufferSize_);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        if (TDebug.TraceAudioConverter)
            TDebug.out("Cannot Read Selected Song");
        bytes = -1;
    }
    if (bytes >= 0) {
        currentBytes += bytes;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

And reading from the buffer section:

```
case playState_ReadData:
            int result;
            index = oggSyncState_.buffer(bufferSize_);
            buffer = oggSyncState_.data;
            bytes = readFromStream(buffer, index, bufferSize_);
            if (TDebug.TraceAudioConverter) {
                TDebug.out("More data : " + bytes);
            }
            // has no data in buffer also
            if (bytes == -1 && bufferSize_ - index == 0) {
                playState = playState_Done;
                if (TDebug.TraceAudioConverter) {
                    TDebug.out("Ogg Stream empty. Settings playState to playState_Done.");
                }
                break;
            }
            else {
                if (bytes != -1) {
                    oggSyncState_.wrote(bytes); 
                }
                if (bytes == 0 && bufferSize_ - index == 0) {
                    if ((oggPage_.eos() != 0) || (oggStreamState_.e_o_s != 0) || (oggPacket_.e_o_s != 0)) {
                        if (TDebug.TraceAudioConverter) {
                            TDebug.out("oggSyncState wrote 0 bytes: settings playState to playState_Done.");
                        }
                        playState = playState_Done;
                    }
                    if (TDebug.TraceAudioConverter) {
                        TDebug.out("oggSyncState wrote 0 bytes: but stream not yet empty.");
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            result = oggSyncState_.pageout(oggPage_);
            if (result == 0) {
                if (TDebug.TraceAudioConverter) {
                    TDebug.out("Setting playState to playState_ReadData.");
                }
                playState = playState_ReadData;
                break;
            } // need more data
            if (result == -1) { // missing or corrupt data at this page position
                if (TDebug.TraceAudioConverter)
                    TDebug.out("Corrupt or missing data in bitstream; setting playState to playState_ReadData");
                playState = playState_ReadData;
                break;
            }

            oggStreamState_.pagein(oggPage_);

            if (TDebug.TraceAudioConverter)
                TDebug.out("Setting playState to playState_WriteData.");
            playState = playState_WriteData;
            break;
```

While reading they are ignoring bytes that are already read from the buffer, so, they'd just skip the last read bytes that are in the buffer.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I unfortunately have yet to put this into practise since I've moved on to to other projects since asking this question... but I really appreciate the detailed input for your solution and I don't want this answer to go to waste so I'm accepting it.